# Best way of using masks to select sub-vectors in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, indexing, mask

We want to select some elements of a 1D array `v_data`. The processing we need to do requires looping over sub-vectors of `v_data`.

Right now I use byte logic like [Gosper's hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gosper%27s_hack) to create an integer `n_mask` whose binary representation corresponds to the indices of `v_data` I want.  `n_mask` can be converted to a binary vector through a method:

```
def num2bv(num, n_len):
    """Convert a number to a binary vector of some length"""
    return [bool((2**ii & num)//(2**ii)) for ii in reversed(range(0, n_len))]
```

Setting `bv_mask = num2bv(n_mask, len(v_data))`, the sub-vector can be recovered by running `v_data[bv_using]`

Is this a bad way to do it? In particular I am concerned that:

- Indexing with binary vectors will be slow in practice
- `num2bv` will be slow in practice
- Ability to use this technique for vectors of any length depends on Python's arbitrary-precision integers, which might be slow or nonportable

Are these valid concerns?

Comment: I  think `num2bv` will indeed be slow. So you may consider replacing it with `np.unpackbits`. This, however, will probably not work on arbitrary precision integers :(

Comment: itertools has a function that does exactly this, it's called [compress](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.compress).  Although it doesn't use bits, it takes any sequence of "truthy/falsy" values (which you should to be able to make via a generator).

Comment: With large `n_len` (like 1000000), `num2bv` is painfully slow.  It's a list comprehension scaling with `n_len`.  By constrast, `np.ix_` is just `np.nonzero`, finding the index of all True, and does the iteration in compiled code.  `v_data[idx]` with the resulting index list is also comparatively fast.

Comment: `vdata[bv_mask]` implicitly does `vdata[np.nonzero(bv_mask)]` (as can be seen in timeits.  `itertools.compress` is useful if `vdata` is a list, but not needed if it is already an `numpy` array.  The array indexing is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the length of your vector it may be much faster to use `itertools.combinations`:

```
In [2] v = np.array(range(15))

In [3]: %time x = [v[num2bv(i,15)] for i in range(2**15)]
CPU times: user 498 ms, sys: 5.83 ms, total: 504 ms
Wall time: 506 ms

In [4]: %time x = [c for i in range(15) for c in combinations(v,i)]
CPU times: user 5.67 ms, sys: 1.53 ms, total: 7.2 ms
Wall time: 6.91 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

An array version of `num2bv` is:

```
def foo(num, n_len):
    c = np.int64(2)**np.arange(n_len)[::-1]
    return (np.bitwise_and(c,num)//c).astype(bool)

In [713]: N=16
In [714]: foo(2**(N//2)-1,N)
Out[714]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
In [715]: np.array(num2bv(2**(N//2)-1,N))
Out[715]: 
array([False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)

In [716]: N=32
In [717]: timeit np.array(num2bv(2**(N//2)-1,N))
10000 loops, best of 3: 39.7 µs per loop
In [718]: timeit foo(2**(N//2)-1,N)
The slowest run took 4.72 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.7 µs per loop
```

But for large `N` the array version starts to run into problems with the integer representation of 2**i.

For larger `N`, the `num2bv` time dominates the indexing, e.g `N=1024`

```
In [734]: timeit num2bv(2**(N//2)-1,N)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.34 ms per loop
In [735]: timeit np.nonzero(num2bv(2**(N//2)-1,N))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.4 ms per loop
In [736]: A=np.ones(N)
In [738]: timeit A[num2bv(2**(N//2)-1,N)]
100 loops, best of 3: 4.39 ms per loop
```

---

`np.binary_repr` returns a string representation.  It makes use Python `bin`.  One way to create the mask is to split it with `list` and let `np.array` convert it to a boolean array

```
In [846]: np.binary_repr(100,16)
Out[846]: '0000000001100100'
In [848]: np.array(list(np.binary_repr(100,16)),bool)
Out[848]: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

It's not quite as fast as `to_numpy_mask_2`, but still quite an improvement over `num2bv`.  And not subject to the size limitation of my earlier `foo`.

```
In [842]: timeit np.array(num2bv(100,120))
10000 loops, best of 3: 166 µs per loop
In [843]: timeit to_numpy_mask_2(100,120)
The slowest run took 5.07 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 7.6 µs per loop
In [850]: timeit np.array(list(np.binary_repr(100,120)),bool)
100000 loops, best of 3: 18 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Combining the `.to_bytes` method of integers with `np.unpackbits` is reasonably fast. A 1,000,000 bit word is converted in less than a ms:

```
import numpy as np
import random
from timeit import timeit

# a slower approach using builtin 'bin' function
def to_numpy_mask_1(n, bits = 120):
    return (np.frombuffer(bin(n + 2**bits)[-bits:].encode('utf8'),
                          dtype=np.uint8)-48).view(bool)

# the real thing based on '.to_bytes'
def to_numpy_mask_2(n, bits = 120):
    return np.unpackbits(np.frombuffer(n.to_bytes((bits-1)//8 + 1, 'big'),
                                       dtype=np.uint8)).view(bool)[-bits:]

# check

base = 2**np.arange(120)[::-1].astype(object)
n = random.randint(0, 2**120)
print(n, base[to_numpy_mask_1(n)].sum(), base[to_numpy_mask_2(n)].sum())

# benchmark

# translation only, no indexing
N = 10**6
n = random.randint(0, 2**N)
print('{:8.6g} secs'.format(timeit(lambda: to_numpy_mask_1(n, bits = N),
                                   number=10)/10))
print('{:8.6g} secs'.format(timeit(lambda: to_numpy_mask_2(n, bits = N),
                                   number=10)/10))

# including indexing
data = np.random.randn(N)
print('{:8.6g} secs'.format(timeit(lambda: data[to_numpy_mask_1(n, bits = N)],
                                   number=10)/10))
print('{:8.6g} secs'.format(timeit(lambda: data[to_numpy_mask_2(n, bits = N)],
                                   number=10)/10))
```

sample output:

```
# 303734588154968662776606530859339928 303734588154968662776606530859339928 303734588154968662776606530859339928
# 0.00622677 secs
# 0.00051558 secs
# 0.0121338 secs
# 0.00697929 secs
```